# Loop over a loop

Tags: python

So far I have gotten my code to loop through five different rows on an excel sheet successfully. I not need it to do this same thing for twelve different sheets. I'm pretty new to python and attempted to put a for loop right on top of my previous for loop, with no success. Here is a snippet of the for loops I am using:

```
 sheetnames = ['0h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '4h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '8h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '12h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '18h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '24h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '36h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '48h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '68h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '78h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '82h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '96h UV Exposure, Roll Direction'] 

 samplenums = [1,2,3,4,5]

 for sheet in sheetnames:
     for dataset in samplenums:
         data = get_data(sheetnames[sheet],dataset)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? `for sheet in sheetnames` iterates over every single element in `sheetnames`, so I’m struggling to find the issue. Of course, it’s near impossible to figure out what’s going on when we’re missing most of the code and data. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: @Alexander, the problem is that Kyle used `sheetnames[sheet]` while sheet is not an int so it cannot be used to index a list. This is why including the error callback is useful to avoid this confusion.

Comment: @lbragile You’re right, nice catch. Can’t believe I missed that. Does this mean there are potentially 2+ problems in here?

Comment: @Alexander not really, I think that is the only problem. Do you see any other issue besides the extra " " (indent) in the code? But as I said in my answer, without knowing what `get_data()` does, we can't know if this will work as OP expected.

Comment: @lbragile Well, the iteration problem that OP seems to be referring to. I don’t know if that was caused entirely by the indexing error, it isn’t clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `sheet` is already an element from `sheetnames` so there is no need to index it (that is actually wrong). You can simply do:

```
for sheet in sheetnames:
  for dataset in samplenums:
    data = get_data(sheet, dataset)
```

Without knowing what `get_data(arg1, arg2)` looks/does there is not much more we can do for you.